# Western Digital portable hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, portable

Is there any software for using the WD 1TB My Passport Ultra that runs in Ubuntu?

Comment: Define the software please to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/272396/how-to-run-full-ubuntu-installation-from-external-hard-drive

Comment: If you mean Ubuntu alternative  to software supplied in package with hard drive, then no, but you should make it more clear in your question, I just formatted mine to one NTFS partition so it is easily usable on both Windows and Ubuntu and it worked without any additional software.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the smartware one-click backup: no. The other smartware utilities are Windows tools that have an equivalent option in Linux (like the SMART toolset). There is a 3rd tools for security where you can password protect the disk. That is possible using encryption but it will not be a 1-click solution.

You also need to remove the hidden partitions on it for it to be mountable in Linux. Requires a firmware update (from Windows) and then you can use Smartware to remove those partitions (not sure if this applies to others than the WDBY8L0020BBK-01).

Answer (score 1):

No need.  Just plug the drive in a USB port and you can start using it (at least that is how it worked for me).  If you want to have specific partitions, you can do that as well, using Gparted.