# Installing Ubuntu 17.04 to an external drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I am pretty new to this and I am trying to boot Ubuntu from a 1Tb extra hard drive. I have the iso installed already but not sure where to go from there. I've read about burning it to the external drive, which isn't working out out for me. I've also seen some posts about partitioning but I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @RahulDhruve, please edit the question and explain what you have and want to achieve: What operating system is installed in the internal drive? How do you want to use Ubuntu (test or use regularly; use in one single computer or as a portable drive in different computers)?

Comment: @karel et. al., Please explain why you do not like this question and my answer. (I am willing to modify or remove my answer, if you think that it causes confusion.)

Comment: @sudodus My explanation is that I do not dislike either this question or your answer to it. In fact, now that you mention it, I may flag the question to be merged if it is closed as a duplicate in order to preserve your answer to it. I did not vote on anything that is posted on this page, merely voted that the question was a duplicate question. The eccentricities of user voting on this question are as baffling!?!? to me as they are to you.

Comment: @sudodus In addition please allow me to share my humble experience with eccentric voting patterns. My design work on another Stack Exchange site gets downvoted "irrationally" imo compared to here makes me ask myself if eccentric voting is somehow motivated by subjective or opinion-based considerations.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want a regular installed Ubuntu system in this target '1Tb extra' hard drive? Or do you want a persistent live system? Both are possible. See this link and links from it,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

- **Backup** whatever data are stored in the 1Tb extra hard drive to another drive or to the 'internet cloud'.
- **Installed system** (more stable, fairly portable)

  - Create a USB boot pendrive with a cloning tool, for example

    - the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator** (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions) or
    - [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) or
    - [**Win32 Disk Imager**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb) or [**Rufus**](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) in Windows.
  - Boot from the USB boot pendrive drive and install Ubuntu to the target 1Tb extra hard drive.

    It will be easier and safer if you **remove the internal drive** before installing to the 1Tb extra hard drive. Otherwise, in UEFI mode, the bootloader will be installed into the internal drive. If it is impossible to remove the internal drive in this target computer, you can create the USB boot drive in another computer. Avoid proprietary drivers! Move the drive to the target computer, and if necessary, install proprieatry drivers (typically for graphics and wifi).
- **Persistent live system** (more portable, fairly stable)

  - Install [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and use it to create a [persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent) system in the 1Tb extra hard drive. You can install mkusb in an existing installed Ubuntu system or in a live system (in a USB boot pendrive).